# kendo chart. onReady Event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to find a way to execute some javascript after the kendo chart has been drawn.

[example here](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwOyO)

I can't seem to find anything in the [documentation.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart)

Thanks

Comment: could you not just run some code after the databound event? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-dataBound

Comment: Thanks!  Can you add this as the answer and I'll give you credit.  I hate answering my own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS per the comment I made.

You could just add the databound event within the initialization as per:

```
dataBound: function(e){ do something here....}
```

for further reading: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-dataBound